# "Cutting" meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "cutting" mean in the following context?

> From the day that Michael Codron became interested in producing the show, I felt the cutting take root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cutting = a piece cut off from a plant that can be used to grow another plant of the same type
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cutting)

In this case the cutting is an analogy for the idea of the show. Codron’s interest in the idea helped give life to it. It grew and expanded into the show that it eventually became. Just as a small cutting, if suitably planted, will root and grow into the final specimen plant.

The use of *take root* rather than *took root* is an interesting point. The answer may be that during the period that is being recalled (“from that day ...”) the author experienced the taking of root as something happening in the present during that period.

Comment: Why "take root"  and not "took root"? It has happened in past.

Comment: I thought the same, you may add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified accordingly.

Comment: _Take_ is not present here, it's infinitive. _I felt it move/grow/shake._ _Feel_ plus infinitive clause means "experience, have a sense of". There is another construction that takes a tensed "that" clause, where the "that" is optional: _I felt [that] it took root_, but "feel" in that construction means "think, conclude, have an opinion".

Comment: A fine point, and one that you may reasonably propose in general. But here is a specific and similar example: “I feel you (to) take hold {= taking hold} of my hand.” Despite the ellipsis (to), this gives *take* a present and active, if gerundial, verbal sense.

Answer (score 1):

Some plants are propagated by cutting off a branch (then referred to as the cutting) and re-planting it. In this case, whatever "the cutting" refers to is starting to grow. See [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_(plant)).

Comment: This is a good answer. I wonder if you might improve it by adding the best definition from the Wikipedia article you cited? (This will avoid link rot, in case the Wikipedia entry gets updated.)